# SharePoint Hyperlink with command-line parameter

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I have a Shortcut in SharePoint that points to an custom .NET EXE file: 
`file://Bluesrv/GROUPS/HSE/Regulatory Compliance/ReCAP/StartApp/StartApp.exe.` 
It works and it opens up with some annoying prompts. BUT I would like to add a command-line parameter to reference an INI file like I do in a desktop shortcut like this: `"\\Server\GROUPS\HSE\Regulatory Compliance\ReCAP\StartApp\MyStartApp.exe"` /cmd/inifile:`"\\Server\GROUPS\HSE\Regulatory Compliance\ReCAP\StartApp\MyStartApp.ini"`

How do I do that in a SharePoint Hyperlink? Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Just to understand your problem better, what do you mean by "SharePoint Hyperlink"? Is it any different than a standard HTML hyperlink?

Comment: I guess not really. It's just a quick launch Hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is to put it into a batch file and reference that instead.